# Getting records upon Financial year 6th April to 5th April using C# and Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a table in which i have Transaction date and i want to get records from last financial year.
for ex. If today is 17-03-2017 i want to get records from 06-04-2017 to till today. then if my today's date is more than 6th April then get records from this year 06-04-2017 to till today.

How can i get records using c# and linq with this condition.?

I have used this linq query

```
List<TransactionMaster> donations = 
    db.TransactionMasters.Where(s => s.DonorId == DonorId && 
    s.TransactionDate.Year >= DateTime.Now.Year - 1 && 
    s.TransactionDate.Month >= 4 && s.TransactionDate.Day >= 6)
    .ToList();
```

but i get records from only year 2016 and month > April.

So how can i get records for financial year 6th April to 5th April?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to compare the dates directly instead of parts, such that:

```
var date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 4,6);
List<TransactionMaster> donations = 
db.TransactionMasters.Where(s => s.DonorId == DonorId && 
s.TransactionDate >= date).ToList();
```

Comment: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: Place `new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 4,6)` outside the query with a variable and pass the variable inside query.

Comment: thanks..... Tetsuya Yamamoto, thats worked for me, thanks a lot janmbaco